# Making a voltage range filter (or a voltage bandpass filter)

Tags: filter

I have been trying to hack together a voltage range filter that will pass voltage to a load only when the input voltage is between 1-2V. My input source can range from 0-3V. (I don't want to scale the voltage with a divider, by the way. I want to filter out voltages between 0-1V and 2-3V into some shunt resistor or something).

I made a basic circuit like below; my intuition was that the first 2 diodes would drop voltage by 0.5V each (the forward voltage of the B520C), leading to 1V voltage drop, but I quickly realized this was not practical.

[image: Preliminary design]

I've been trying recall my electrical engineering knowledge, but I feel like I am missing something -- I think the answer is to use opamps, maybe? where I use a comparator to check if the voltage is within my range, use an opamp to pass it with gain of 1? Or maybe transistors.

Any help in pointing me int he right direction (or even a solution!) would be much appreciated.

Comment: "Window Comparator".

Comment: 2 comparators and a series high pass switch with active low controlled FET

Comment: Thank you @brhans, would have loved to mark you as accept if it had been an answer. Your comment was enough to get me there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this can't be done with just passive components -- you'll need some transistors and/or comparators.

With comparators, set one up to detect if VIN > 1 V, the other if VIN < 2 V. Then AND the 2 outputs together and use that signal to drive a pass transistor (PMOS FET, or even a PNP would work).